# Lua script for krakend

Tags: lua, krakend

I written a simply krakend.json configuration to configure my endpoint. This configuration call a Lua script, for the moment, it prints only the body response.

```
{
      "version": 2,
      "extra_config": {
        "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-gologging": {
          "level":  "DEBUG",
          "prefix": "[KRAKEND]",
          "syslog": false,
          "stdout": true
        },
        "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-metrics": {
          "collection_time": "60s",
          "proxy_disabled": false,
          "router_disabled": false,
          "backend_disabled": false,
          "endpoint_disabled": false,
          "listen_address": ":8090"
        }
      },
      "timeout": "3000ms",
      "cache_ttl": "300s",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "name": "myregistrydomain.com",
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "endpoint": "/models/{group-id}",
          "method": "GET",
          "output_encoding": "json",
            "headers_to_pass": [
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Type"
          ],
    
          "backend": [
            {
              "url_pattern": "myregistrydomain/get-models-by-group/group-id/{group-id}",
              "timeout": "10s",
              "encoding": "no-op",
              "sd": "static",
              "host": ["myregistrydomain"],
              "disable_host_sanitize": "false",
              "extra_config": {
                  "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend/http": {
                      "return_error_details": "backend_models"
                  },
                  "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-lua/proxy/backend": {
                      "sources": ["file1.lua"],
                      "post": "check(response);",
                      "live": true,
                      "allow_open_libs": true,
                      "skip_next": false
                  }
              }
            }
          ],
          "querystring_params": [
            "{group-id}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The Lua function called is:

```
function check(response)
    print("**")
    local r = response.load()
    print(r:body())
end
```

At the moment the print body work properly, I can see all the json response. But in my postman request I see an empty body response.
I wuold use the Lua function only to check if the body response contains the string "error"

My principal question is  why on the log I can see the body response instead in postman my body is empty?

Comment: and what is your question? don't you know how to check wether a string contains the word error?

Comment: No. My question is why on the log I can see the body response instead in postman my body is empty? thanks for the question I edited my principal request

Comment: Your function prints the content on the console as expected, but you are not using any setter to change the response body.